# Overriding GetItem Method of ArrayAdapter in Monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a class that override ArrayAdapter in my monodroid app. It used to create an auto complete for a text view. Its code is:

```
class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter: ArrayAdapter  <String>  ,IFilterable 
{
    private List<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId):
        base(context,textViewResourceId)
        {

        }

    public override int Count 
     {
        get 
        {
            return base.Count;
        }
    }

    public override  String GetItem (int position)
    {
        return resultList[position];
    }


}
```

but it gives this error:

```
 cannot override inherited member 'Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter<string>.GetItem(int)' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override (CS0506)
```

I am confused. What is this error for? surely GetItem method is virtual in base class and I used the override word. What is this error?

Answer (score 5):

You will be able to override it if you extend ArrayAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter<String> and use this signature for GetItem:

```
public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I've always inherited from **BaseAdapter** and passed the list of items as a parameter to the constructor

Here's an example of how I do it

```
public class ImageAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
            private readonly List<string> _imagesUrls;
            private readonly BaseActivity _activity;

            public ImageAdapter(BaseActivity activity, List<string> imagesUrls)
            {
                    _activity = activity;
                    _imagesUrls = imagesUrls;               
            }

            public override Object GetItem(int position)
            {
                    return null;
            }

            public override long GetItemId(int position)
            {
                    return 0;
            }

            public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                    ImageView imageView;

                    if (convertView == null)
                    {
                            imageView = new ImageView(_context);
                            imageView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(Misc.ImageThumbWidth, Misc.ImageThumbWidth);
                            imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
                            imageView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
                    }

                    _activity.DisplayImage(_imagesUrls[position], imageView);

                    return imageView;
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                    get { return _imagesUrls.Count; }
            }
    }
```

Note that in this method

```
public override Object GetItem(int position)
{
    return null;
}
```

**Object** is actually **Java.Lang.Object**

Comment: By base adapter i can make return type String and also override methods fo Ifiltrable is not accasble

Answer (score 0):

[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) is a public class implements [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) which is an interface. ArrayAdapter has already implement the `GetItem(int position)` method which is [an abstract method in BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#inhmethods) which is an inherited method from [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), so you don't need to implement it again and overriding is of course not allowed.

Comment: Please look at this:https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/autocomplete-android In this sample code getItem(int) is overrided.

Comment: By default, JAVA methods are virtual, while C# methods are non-virtual.

Answer (score -2):

place ("@override") Annotation above overriden method getitem(int)

Comment: The OP is about monodroid i.e. C# not Java : so there is no @ override, in C# it would be the keyword override, and in C# (as @Arron He points out) methods are not virtual by default so in this case you can't use the override keyword - as this particular method is not marked as virtual or override. But in java that would work - thanks.